# username containing hyphens with psycopg2 running under Anaconda

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a postgres username that contains a hyphen (example: `'user-1'`).
The following code works with python 2.6.3, but not with Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit). I tried both single and double quotes around the username.
Any ideas?

```
username = 'user-1'
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(
            database = database,
            user = username,
            password = password,
            host = hostname
        )
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database."
```

The code errors with:

> "/usr/local/apps/python/anaconda-current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**i‌​nit**.py", line 164, in connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user-1

Comment: remove the try-except to see (and post) the whole error message.

Comment: File "/usr/local/apps/python/anaconda-current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user-1"

Comment: That is a password error, I don't see anything about invalid syntax

Comment: I don't get the error when I run the code with python 2.6.3

Comment: it turns out that the pw was being read-in from a file and has a mix of upper and lowercase

Comment: The problem actually had to do with an end of line character that wasn't being stripped off of the password.  It works now.  Thanks.